# Merge cells if another cell has the same value

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula, match, vlookup

I have data in Excel like so:

```
Column1    Column2    Column3    Total
  37         45          61      
  37         68          99      
 123         76          12      
 ...
```

I want to produce the following:

```
Column1    Column2    Column3    Total
  37         45          61      45, 68
  37         68          99      
 123         76          12      76,...
 ...
```

If column1 of row1 has the same value with another row's column1 then put its column2 value in total with a comma.

Comment: 3rd row output must be 123. How it should be 76?

Comment: It takes column2 value

Comment: There is not enough information here to understand your exact desired output.  Your example does not even use column3 and it is still unclear on what is even happening with the relationship between 1 and 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming 100 rows in total, please try:

```
=IF(ISERROR(MATCH(A2,A3:A$100,0)),"",B2&", "&VLOOKUP(A2,A3:B$100,2,0))
```

Comment: This is only for two times. If i have more values matched?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have your column 1 sorted, guess this should work:
Cell D2 =IF(A2=A1,IF(D1="",C1&", "&C2,D1&", "&C2),"")
This is my test case... It gives the required total in the last repeated no. Hope its ok

> C1 C2 C3 Tot
>   37  45 61 
>   37  68 99 61,99 
>   123 76 12  
>   123 24 34 12,34 
>   123 35 66 12,34,66 
>   144 62 35